# How to express conditions of the form "template T is a..." using concepts?

Tags: c++, c++-concepts, c++20

It is easy to express things like "type T is a container of E":

```
template <class T, class E>
concept bool is_container = requires(T t, E e) {
    { t.push_back(e) } -> void;
};

template <class T, class E> requires is_container<T,E>
void moo()
{
    T t; E e;
    t.push_back(e);
}
```

(What exactly is being checked is not so important).

Now I need to express a condition like this: "for *any* type E, T is a container".

```
template <template<class> class T> requires is_container<T>
void moo()
{
    T<int> ti; 
    ti.push_back(1);
    T<std::string> ts;
    ts.push_back("abc"s);
}
```

How do I write `is_container` in this case?

Comment: How can we be sure than every `C<T>` passes a given concept (as user can add specialization) ?

Comment: Here your code only requires that `T<int>` and `T<std::string>` are container...

Comment: @Jarod the code of moo is just an example, the user doesn't know and isn't interested in what specific types T is instantiated with.

Comment: @Jarod42 "How can we be sure than every C<T> passes a given concept" This is an interesting point. In general we cannot know which specialisations will be there. So it looks like this is not really possible.

Comment: maybe with introspection you would be able to loop through all the specializations of `T` and have a `require` for each specialization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ templates lack [parametricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametricity). Given a template, it is only possible to check properties of its specific instantiations but not of the template itself (or "all its instantiations", as it were). Different instantiations may have different properties.

So it is apparently impossible to write concepts like the second variant of `is_container`.

Here's a very simple, hackish, partial workaround. The idea is that if a template instantiates and works for some random type, it's likely to work for other types too. Of course uncontrolled specialisations and advanced template magic will break this assumption, but then we're just back to square one with regular unchecked templates.

```
template <class T, class E>
concept bool is_container = requires(T t, E e) {
    { t.push_back(e) } -> void;
};

struct random {};

template <template<class> class T>
concept bool is_generic_container = is_container<T<random>, random>;
```

Answer (score 4):

Like many impossible things in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), this is equivalent to solving Halt.

You have an arbitrary function in a Turing complete language (your template) and wish to determine if every output of your function (every instance of the template) satisfies some property.

Rice's theorem says this is impossible.

This is one of the disadvantages of a Turing-complete metaprogramming language like templates.

Now you can carry the template around and check it against specific types.  But in a sufficiently complex program this is a lot like the problem concepts where invented to solve; errors at interface instead of deep in implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you are asking for is not possible in the way you hinted at, but with a simple workaround you can achieve the same result.

To know that `T<E>` is a container for any type `E`, the compiler would need to instanciate `T<E>` for every possible `E` and check against the condition, which is impossible, as there are infinitely many possbile types `T<E>` (imagine for example chains `T<T<E>>`).

What you can do, is to derive all your container classes (those which are containers for any `E`) from a common base class (a tag).

```
struct container_tag { };

template<class E>
class existing_container_class : public container_tag
{
public:
    using value_type = E;
    /* ... */
};
```

Then write a concept like this one:

```
template<class T>
concept bool concept_container = std::is_base_of_v<container_tag, T>;
```

And use it like this:

```
template<concept_container T>
void moo() {
    T t;
    T::value_type e;
    t.push_back(e);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately tagging is not really feasible because we want to be able to concept-check standard library components and third party components.